# Excel - list entities (items)

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

Friends,
I need to list all the unique entities (items) in a Excel spreadsheet, how to?

E.g.

```
**List1**
1
1
1.1
2
a
a
aa
b
c
c
```

And I need a certain function that returns:

```
**Entities**
1
1.1
2
a
aa
b
c
```

Then I can count the occurence of each entity (using COUNTIF function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B2** enter the *array formula:*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$11),0)),"")
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,B2)
```

and copy down.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply pivot to your list to identify uniqueness. One you have identified the unique list, you can apply count if formula.